# using wget with php to download images generated via script remotely

Tags: php, shell, wget

Good day all.

I have this problem, I need to download a lot of images, I have the ppossibility to use wget to achieve this, but I got some problems.

first, I have try wget itself:

```
system('wget -q http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif -O test2.gif');
```

ok, it works, I can do it ...
So, I changed the parameters, putting the real URL and a subdirectory where to save:

```
system('wget -q -nH '.$row['foto'].' -O ./img/'.$row['modello'].'.jpg');
```

that is been parsed in:

```
wget -q -nH http://server.com/main.php?action=exec&task=show_image&task_arg=23456&m=not&ft=product_full_image_1&auth=d84a122342332ff2d1dssssff06d0199 -O ./img/0561142.jpg
```

this time I get a werid result, something like a thousands 11 bytes files called main.php?action=exec### have been created in the same directory of the script (note that ### is a 3 digit number ).

I understand that there is something wrong...maybe url parameters? maybe the subdirectory? what I'm messing? is `system` the god choiche? or maybe `exec` is better? or whatever?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, please dont just pass database values like that in, If someone ever finds an sql injection, they could have shell access too !

Comment: it is actually in test, of course I will never put this in production :D

Comment: Even for test, Use the php curl library

Comment: so it is best to use crul instead of wget? are you saying this?

Comment: use php curl its actually php code rather than trying to use wget though exec

Comment: And why i get this strange behavour?

Comment: very likely exatcly what i said earlier its not escaped `escapeshellarg` around both of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampersand, and other characters, has special meaning in shell syntax. If you really can't use [PHP's built-in cURL library](https://php.net/curl) you should at least [escape the shell options](https://www.php.net/escapeshellarg) before adding them to the command.